# Graphical representation of a parameterization

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

Consider the function

$f: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^2; f(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(2t))$

Make a sketch and or describe the function.

I get the coordinates in the $(x,y)$ plane by $x(t)=\cos(t)$ and $y(t) = \sin(2t)$. Accordingly, for $t \in [0,2 \pi]$ a value table is to be prepared and a graph is to be drawn. So for t=0 the point would be $(\cos(0), \sin(2*0)) = (1,0)$ etc. so for example I could make a table of values for $t=0, t=\frac{1}{10} \pi$, $t=\frac{2}{10} \pi$ etc up to $2 \pi$. When I do this, the graph looks like a lying eight - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If $t\in[0,2\pi]$, then $\sin(2t)=2\sin(t)\cos(t)$. Therefore, if $t\in[0,\pi]$, then
$$
\sin(2t)=2\sqrt{1-\cos^2(t)}\,\cos(t),
$$
and if $t\in[\pi,2\pi]$, then
$$
\sin(2t)=-2\sqrt{1-\cos^2(t)}\,\cos(t).
$$
So, your curve is the union of the graphs of $x\mapsto\color{blue}{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $x\mapsto\color{orange}{-2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ (with $x\in[-1,1]$). And the union of these graphs is indeed a line like a sideways figure $8$:

[image]

Comment: thank you, but is my way with the value table also correct?

Comment: I don't think so. Your approach gives you an idea of what the curve looks like, but I don't think it is rigorous enough. Besides, it depends upon computing things like $\sin\left(\frac\pi{10}\right)$, which require a computer or a calculator. My approach doesn't.

Comment: where is the cos(t) gone? you are only concentrating on sin(2t)?

Comment: I focused on $\sin(2t)$ because it is the more complex part of $(\cos(t),\sin(2t))$. But, after having noted that $\sin(2t)=\pm2\cos(t)\sqrt{1-\cos^2(t)}$, $\cos(t)$ has reappeared: I used the fact that$$\left(\cos(t),\sin(2t)\right)=\left(\cos(t),\pm2\cos(t)\sqrt{1-\cos^2(t)}\right),$$which is of the form $\left(x,\pm2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$, for some $x\in[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a value table is probably the best method graphing parametric equations. 
You can verify your plot on Desmos by inputting $f(t)$ and setting the range to $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$, showing a lying eight like you described.